# Django , I have created a post model and a basic user authentication, for my index page i want to show only posts by current user ,

Tags: django-templates, django-views

Create your models here.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my html

```
     <!-- templates/home.html -->
     {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}

     <h1>Homepage.</h1>

    <ul>
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
       {% for post in deeppost %}
     <li>{{post.title}}</li></a><p>{{post.body}}</p>Created by- 
    {{post.author}}

    {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
   <p>You are not logged in. Please goto the login Page by clicking on the login link above </p>

   {% endif %}
    </ul>-
     {% endblock %}
```

I want to understand how do i only return posts of the user who is currently logged in , I cant understand as i am new to django and programming in general

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView
   from .models import Post
   # Create your views here.

  def index(request):
       return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")


    class HomePageView(ListView):

         model = Post
      template_name = 'home.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
    context['deeppost'] = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return context




     class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
       template_name = 'about.html'

       class BlogListView(ListView):
      model = Post
        template_name = 'home.html'



    class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
      model = Post
      template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

have added the the views that you had asked for , i would like to know how to change it get the results that are expected , also i want to understand how do you have custom user form and image uploads

Comment: please add your views.py

Comment: to get all post whose `author` is current user , `queryset = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)`

Comment: where do i add this

Comment: whre does the query set get added

Comment: request.user is giving an error that request not defined do i have to import something , ?

Answer (score 0):

On your view.py you need to filter the data:

```
deeppost = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
```

PS: share your current view so I can update the answer

Comment: please see the view that you had asked for

Comment: where are you populating the deeppost ?

Comment: what do you mean ? , From the admin site ,

Answer (score 0):

From your model

- Its actually keep saving all posts which posted by a user.
- and you have created One-To-Many relationships for User and Posts.
- So each User has many posts.

Showing only posts for the current user, you have to build a [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) in your **views.py** with deeppost, Now deeppost will be filtered for a current user (code mentioned below), But you are used [ClassBasedViews](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) so you have to override get_queryset method here.

Better you can go with function based views, If you new for Django.

```
class PostsList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'posts/user_posts.html

    def get_queryset(self):
       """
       Return the list of posts created by User.
       """
       qs = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)
       return qs
```

Finally render the template with particular filtered posts in your templates.

Comment: yes can please some one explain step by step as i am new to programming in general

Comment: which file do i add it and where , Please understand i am learning on my own , thank you.

Comment: You go with function based views so that you can get a better understanding of the django code execution flow.

Comment: what do you mean , ? i am new to programming